# decentralized membership frameworks

Tags: frameworks, network-protocols

I remember seeing a framework that simply handled the creation of a peer to peer decentralized network. I believe it used a gossip protocol to handle the data exchange and it simply had function calls for on join, on leave, and an arbitrary message to kick off something else. I can't for the life of me find it, ring a bell for anyone?

Other notes, on it's website it had a section where it explained how it was different from stuff like zookeeper, cassandra etc.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what I was looking for, [Serf](http://www.serfdom.io/).

From their website: Serf is a service discovery and orchestration tool that is decentralized, highly available, and fault tolerant. Serf runs on every major platform: Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows. It is extremely lightweight: it uses 5 to 10 MB of resident memory and primarily communicates using infrequent UDP messages.